# Hibernate Criteria SubQuery case insensitive issue

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some problems with a criteria like the following.
It works fine, but I need the Subqueries.in condition to be case insensitive.

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Row.class, "row")
        .createAlias("subRows", "s_row").createAlias("s_row.fields", "field");

fields = DetachedCriteria.forClass(SubRowField.class, "field").add(
Property.forName("field.subRow.id").eqProperty(
"s_row.id")).add(Restrictions.eq("field.fieldName", "somename"));

criteria.add(Subqueries.in("somevalue", fields.setProjection(Projections.property("field.value"))))
```

Maybe is there another way to achieve this result ?

If any of you has an idea it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

L0ck3

P.S. : I can provide the data model structure if needed, but I think the code should be enough.

Comment: do you know how to write similar query in sql?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just run it through a filter or preprocessor that normalizes the case?